# "tolerable elapsed time" meaning and a fancier word for this

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

Found usage:

“Big data is a term applied to data sets whose size is beyond the ability of commonly used software tools to capture, manage, and process the data within a **tolerable elapsed time**”.

What does "tolerable elapsed time" really mean? I do understand it in this context, but still I'd be happy if someone explains this in more details.

In addition, is there a better and a fancier word for meaning: "tolerable elapsed time"? I'd be happy to see this one.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: One thing I just came up with is, "**short time iteration**".

Comment: **iteration** usually implies repetition.

Comment: Yes, I realized that afterwards. OOps! My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that it's any fancier, but it's a bit more jargon-y to say "in a reasonable (or tolerable) timeframe"

Comment: "within a reasonable (or tolerable) timeframe", can I exclude "(or tolerable)" line?

Comment: You could use either word, reasonable or tolerable, depending on what you wanted to convey. I would choose 'reasonable' unless you need to imply a sense of urgency.

Answer (score 0):

It means that potential users of "big data" find that its processing takes more time than they're willing to wait.

Consider "unacceptable turnaround."